# Encodeuri component postman

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de consumir un servicio rest,
al probarlo desde postman (por un algoritmo viejo de seguridad) hay que hacerle un encode de lo contrario no funciona en el postman
Ahora desde c# quiero hacer lo mismo pensaba que el encode de postman lo transformaba a UTF8 pero al hacerlodesde C# no le hizo ninguna transformacion y saca el error al tratar de consumir el servicio desde .net c#:

byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(mensaje);
mensaje = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes1);

[image]
Como les decia el encode de postman si funciona y toma una cadena asi:
UGwLAz8/CmE/Pyl+
transformandola asi
queda asi para que funcione: UGwLAz8%2FCmE%2FPyl%2B
La pregunta es que funcion en C# haria este encodeuricomponent o en que
se debe transforma porque utf8 no hizo nada
les agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `Uri.EscapeDataString` conviertes el string a ese formato

Demo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string entrada = "UGwLAz8/CmE/Pyl+";
    string salida = Uri.EscapeDataString(entrada);
            
    Console.WriteLine(salida);
}
```

Salida:

```
UGwLAz8%2FCmE%2FPyl%2B
```

Comment: Si funciono!!! gracias. no conocia esa funcion  que chevere